# which version of Jave Runtime Environment?

Tags: java, jre

if I have a 64 bit Windows 10 laptop, which version of Java SE Runtime Environment 8u102, Windows x64 Offline or Windows x86 Offline?

Comment: Clearly use 8u102 x64

Comment: @DrZoo Clearly not. Both versions will work and it depends on whether the application using the JRE is 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: @zagrimsan There are also differences depending on how much memory a Java app requires. A 64bit JRE can allocate more memory ...

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your Java Application, or software that will use the Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE).

Most standalone application (not via browser) will be happy with either x86 or x64 (32 / 64 bit) Java. You may be better off using 64 bit if your OS AND whatever standalone application that needs Java can supports 64 bit.

If you plan to use Java on the browser, most browser are 32-bit, and if you ONLY have Java 64 bit, the browser will not be able to use it. This is when you need to have Java 32 bit (x86).

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: Whatever https://java.com/ tells you to install (it will autodetect your browser and operating system).

More nuanced answer: If you want to use Java as a browser plugin, choose the version that matches your browser.  If you just want to use it without the browser, 64-bit is better.  It's also fine to install both; just make sure that when you update, you update both.

Source: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/choosing_64_and_or_32